# How to properly update visual studio sources files/directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My cpps and headers files were messy on visual studio, then I organized it manually on the directories.

The problem is visual studio still trying to compile over the old files names and directories that I have already changed, I'm getting a lot of

C1083: No such file or directory and 
MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of ...

But I deleted them and I want to visual studio recognizes it.

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the old ones and add the news ones into the project.

Comment: I removed manually on the folder, then I clicked on update at visual studio, there is no old file there to remove

Comment: Fixed it!
I had to edit the .vcxproj file wich included the compiles paths for all files!

Thanks !